# Compiling LibGDX on Android with Jvdroid

Tags: java, android, maven, compilation, libgdx

I am getting back to coding Java after two years, which I sorely missed.  I need to set up an environment on Android for game making, so I purchased Jvdroid for the ability to process Maven files from GitHub on my phone.  Jvdroid resembles a similarity to IntelliJ  from JetBrains with much less features.  LibGDX offers a Project making executable JAR, yet the file limits it self only to Desktop operating systems.

My problem then focuses on getting a LibGDX Project for a hopefully simple set up.  It is possible that Jvdroid may still say no to downloading required libraries for compiling.  I will not be able to use LibGDX I think on Android, if that proves true.

I am familiar enough with GitHub, where I can just download a working sample Project for LibGDX from a different programmer's repository or LibGDX's own.  Flappy Bird is a bad example, but that serves just to give you an idea.

If that concept fails, then I would possibly consider an alternate game engine like Cocos2D or Haxe.  I need some thing with GLTF file support in the future, because of my love for Daz3D.  I also restrict my coding to Java.

I appreciate insight for how LibGDX may possibly compile and run on Android.  I believe producing an APK would be comparably good effort at that far of a point.  I am aware a couple of other programmers have successfully done such with minimal Project files at the least of it all.

Thank you for reading and your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Jvdroid, but I would have looked at [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app) and see if your device's OS version is compatible and your device has adequate storage (RAM/Flash). Termux simulates a Linux terminal environment (with limits), so it helps to be familiar with the command line interface. Do realize that there are [preferred places to download](https://github.com/termux/termux-app#f-droid) as [Google Play policies no longer compatible](https://github.com/termux/termux-app#google-play-store-deprecated).

A quick search brings up projects like: https://github.com/ravener/libgdx-termux which may be a jumping off point.

Of course, if you can do development on a PC - your experience will be better, due to each new Android version adding restrictions to such an environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I use Termux to connect with my personal web server, so your suggestion of the GitHub repository is a good surprise.  I am not sure if it will help you, yet voxfor.com offers lifetime single payment only Linux web servers.  I also use APKPure to help keep many Android Apps updated on Google Play, like Termux, so you could consider that if you prefer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Doom If you feel my answer was helpful, please accept it. StackOverflow is for programming questions. As you are already aware of Termux, the comments should be kept to the topic.